# How do I include 'undefined' in the array returned by mongodb's distinct() operator when the field does not exist?

Tags: mongodb, distinct, nosql

I would like to get an array of distinct values of a certain field in a mongodb collection. However, the field is optional and if any document does not have the field, I want the array to include the value 'undefined' (or null or any indication). The distinct operator seems to ignore any documents that do not have the field, rather than include 'undefined' in the array of distinct values. Does anyone know how I can override this behavior?

Documentation for the distinct operator: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/

I am getting around this now by making a second db call that counts the items with this field equal to undefined, but I would like to do it in one call.

Comment: Can you post the query you're using?  Your question doesn't really make sense.  Distinct will give you the distinct values that are set for that field.  If 'undefined' is a value, it should be in the list.  If a document doesn't have that field set, then there's no value for the field in that document!

Comment: Actually his question *makes* sense. It is a bit strange, I agree, and what he wants is not really the kind of things MongoDB is supposed to do but his request is clear : "I want in a single DB query or the simplest way an array with all distinct values of a given field in a collection, plus the value `undefined` if there is at least one element that does not have this field in my collection."

Comment: Also notice that if a field has the value `undefined`, the resulting array of `distinct` query will contain `null` and not `undefined`.

Comment: @dgiugg, that's correct (and a better way of stating my question). Null would be fine if that were the case.

Comment: If you have any control over the documents upon insertion, can you insert them with 'undefined' (or some other default placeholder value)?  Distinct is behaving correctly, IMO, as if a field is null, then that's not a value.  That is different from a document not having the field at all, of course.

Comment: @BetseyBenagh this is not a good suggestion - there is no reason to artificially bloat documents with values they don't have - the whole point of flexible schema is to be able to only set fields in documents where the value makes sense.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky, it depends in what is most important. If the documents are likely to have that field added later, my understanding is that it's better to have a placeholder Value than increase the size of the document. Also, if knowing in one database call that documents have some "null" value is important, well, disk is cheap.

Comment: @BetseyBenagh, I ended up requiring the field in the schema and assigning a default value if it does not exist when adding/updating. It was more important for my application to have an efficient way to get the distinct values and now I can use the distinct() operator alone. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using aggregation framework:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
  {$group:{_id:"$myField"}}
}
```

It will include null value if any documents don't have the field, or have it as `null` value.

Comment: You can optionally add a second stage "{$group:{_id:null,distincts:{$push:"$_id"}}}" to put all the values into a single array.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't see a way to do what you're describing in one call.

However, to optimize what you're doing now:

I think you're doing something like:

```
db.myCollection.count({$not: {$exists: myfield}})
```

If your collection is large, this can get slow.  You might consider

```
db.myCollection.findOne({$not: {$exists: myfield}})
```

If no documents exist without "myfield", it will return null.

Comment: that won't be any faster, since count will use the same index that findOne would try to use, but $not and $exists combination will probably trigger ignoring of the index anyway.  If you are going to do this, why not just use $exists:false or {"myField":null}?